# Es posible ejecutar dos JSF en una misma pagina?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, java-ee

Quisiera saber si es posible por ejemplo, en un index.xhtml tener un div que liste un conjunto de usuarios y en otro div dentro del mismo index.xhtml desplegar un JSF para agregar nuevos usuarios y al darle "Enviar" se recargue el primer div con el nuevo usuario utilizando Ajax.

Estoy estudiando JSF en estos momentos y tengo dos JSF separados...uno para listar los usuarios y otro para agregar nuevos usuarios pero me gustaria hacer todo ese proceso en una misma pagina para que se vea en tiempo real la adicion del usuario (como un chat, donde de tu lado izquierdo vez los mensajes pero de tu lado derecho ingresas un nuevo mensaje)

Es posible con JSF y Ajax o tendria que haber alguna integracion con JavaScript?

Gracias de antemano

PD, Aca les dejo los JSF que tengo. Basicamente, el primero despliega el listado de partidos politicos, y el segundo se encarga de ingresar un nuevo partido.

Me gustaria saber si se puede combinar estos dos JSF en uno solo usando DIV para que, ingresando un nuevo partido (digamos en un DIV del lado derecho) automaticamente se actualice el listado (del DIV del lado izquierdo) sin necesidad de refrescar toda la pagina (me imagino que usando ajax pero ustedes diran)

```java
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:composition template="templates/main.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
            <h1>Todos los partidos</h1>
            <h:form>
                <h:dataTable class="table" value="#{listPoliticalPartiesBean.allParties}" var="p">

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Nombre del partido</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{p.name}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Nombre del candidato</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{p.candidate}"/>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
                <!--Boton para la ir a la creacion de partido politico -->
                <h:commandLink 
                    value="Registrar nuevo partido" 
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    action="registerPP">

                </h:commandLink>
            </h:form>        
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

```java
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:composition template="templates/main.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="title">Registro de partidos politicos</ui:define>        

        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>
                Nombre del partido politico:<br/>
                <h:inputText value="#{registerPoliticalPartyBean.tempName}"/><br/>
                Nombre del candidato:<br/>
                <h:inputText value="#{registerPoliticalPartyBean.tempCandidate}"/><br/>
                <br/>
                <h:commandButton value="Registrar" action="#{registerPoliticalPartyBean.register}"/>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</html>
```

Gracias de antemano nuevamente

Comment: Si, es totalmente posible hacer esto con JSF y sin necesidad de usar javascript. Tienes una sola página xhtml y la lógica para hacer esto en un solo ManagedBean.

Comment: @AlejandroGiorgi, debes poner el comentario como respuesta y, si esto funciona, debe ser la respuesta aceptada

Comment: Lo que pasa es que es una pregunta muy amplia. Creo que habría que esperar que @SecaidaDevStudent tenga algún ejemplo de lo que intentó hacer para que podamos ayudarlo mejor.

Comment: @AlejandroGiorgi perdon por la tardanza en responder (trabajo trabajo) acabo de editar mi publicacion e inclui los JSF que tengo..Saludos

Answer (score 0):

JSF soporta ajax out of the box, esto significa que no necesitas agregar javascript adicional (js puro o jquery) para poder hacer un ajax en las vistas. JSF agregará todo el javascript necesario por ti.

Cuando ejecutas un ajax puedes indicarle a JSF que parte de la vista quieres que se actualice al terminar la ejecución. En tu caso sería la tabla.

Suponiendo que unes estas dos vistas en una sola, diría que intentes hacer algo así:

```
<h:commandButton value="Registrar" 
    action="#{registerPoliticalPartyBean.register}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":partiesTable" />
</h:commandButton>
```

El atributo render de la etiqueta f:ajax especifica que elemento de la pantalla hay que actualizar, por lo que tu tabla debería tener id (o puedes envolver la tabla en un elemento h:panelGroup y pornerle este id)

Por ejemplo así:

```
    <h:dataTable id="partiesTable" class="table" value="# 
    {listPoliticalPartiesBean.allParties}" var="p">
```

Según tu ejemplo quizás esto funcione:

```
    <h1>Todos los partidos</h1>
    <h:dataTable id="partiesTable" class="table" value="# 
        {listPoliticalPartiesBean.allParties}" var="p">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Nombre del partido</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{p.name}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Nombre del candidato</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{p.candidate}"/>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:form>
        Nombre del partido politico:<br/>
        <h:inputText value="#{registerPoliticalPartyBean.tempName}"/><br/>
        Nombre del candidato:<br/>
        <h:inputText value="#{registerPoliticalPartyBean.tempCandidate}"/><br/>
        <br/>
        <h:commandButton value="Registrar" 
            action="#{registerPoliticalPartyBean.register}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":partiesTable" />
        </commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

A veces es algo complicado configurar bien el id de cada componente porque jsf agrega uno autómaticamente, ten en cuenta esto.

Por último, estoy asumiendo que tu ManagedBean **listPoliticalPartiesBean** obtiene de la base de datos todos los partidos en el método **allParties**

Comment: Hola Alejandro gracias por tu respuesta y perdon por responder hasta este momento...me ha ayudado mucho tu informacion